# I'm new to threejs, how to create a sky dome

Tags: three.js

I'm pretty new to three.js and I tried for hours to create a skybox/skydome for a better visual feeling to my world (in this case space). Googled, checked tutorials, asked here on StackOverflow. And nothing worked, or I got a silly and dumb answer here on SO. Question is simple: how to make a skybox/dome?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This is how you do a skydome in threejs.**

```
var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100000, 25, 25);
```

First the geometry. I wanted it big and made it big

```
    var loader  = new THREE.TextureLoader(),
        texture = loader.load( "images/space.jpg" );
```

Loads the texture of your background space. One thing here is that you need it to run through a server to be able to load the texture. I use wamp or brackets preview.

Create the material for the skybox here

```
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
        map: texture,
});
```

Set everything together and add it to the scene here.

```
    var sky = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, material);
    sky.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
    scene.add(sky);
```

This might not be the best solution for this, but it´s easy specially for a beginner in threejs. Easy to understand and create.

Comment: you cannot possibly answer your own question in zero time. why ask it in the first place?

Comment: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Read this and you will undestand why I did what I did, have a nice day!

Comment: 1. Why is `depthWrite` false?   2. What is `function(){ ... } for?   3. Why is side `THREE.DoubleSide`?

Comment: 1. So that you can see the objects you have inside the sphere when you are outside, not needed tho. 2. I take that away, ty. 3. if not DoubleSide you cant see the texture inside the sphere. Any other better solution?

Comment: Outside the skydome? Cameras are usually inside the skydome. Use `THREE.BackSide`.

Comment: Thanks, added that now.

Comment: Again. Why is `depthWrite` false?

Comment: You are right, I can´t explain why I had that and took that away aswell. I know what it does (handles z-index).

Comment: With all due respect to you, it is of no help to beginners if you post misinformation. Wait until you become sufficiently knowledgeable in a topic before you post answers.

Comment: I understand, but the lack of information I found when I did this were the reason I made this. Just wanted to be helpfull and spare some other person hours of work for something thats pretty simple. The documentation on three.js is not always the easiest to read.

Comment: I appreciated this so much. Next time I will try document my own solved problem!

Comment: The gatekeeping is strong on this post. Thanks for the answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can load  image as texture and apply that on innerside of a sphere geometry to emulate skydome.

Complete solution with error callback for future reference

```
        //SKY
        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader.load(
          "./assets/universe.png",
          this.onLoad,
          this.onProgress,
          this.onError
        );

      onLoad = texture => {

        var objGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(30, 60, 60);
        var objMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map: texture,
          shading: THREE.FlatShading
        });
        objMaterial.side = THREE.BackSide;
        this.earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(objGeometry, objMaterial);

        scene.add(this.earthMesh);
        //start animation
        this.start();
      };

      onProgress = xhr => {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
      };

      // Function called when download errors
      onError = error => {
        console.log("An error happened" + error);
      };
```